# How to convert dot (.) to string in Laravel with Mysql query's function whereColumn

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-9

I have this kind of error in a subid I have. In the argument that laravel automatically place an ' after that. How can I get rid of that or how can I convert my `.` to not to be string concatenate expression and convert it to become string instead?

[image]

Here is my controller code which have the syntax :

```
 public function datavolumechart() {
    $volume = lokasipekerjaan::select(
        DB::raw("YEAR(tanggal) as year"),
        DB::raw("SUM(volume) as total_volume
        "),
    )->havingRaw('total_volume < 100000000', [1])->whereColumn('subid','1.A.A.1')->orderBy(DB::raw("WEEK(tanggal)"))
    ->groupBy(DB::raw("WEEK(tanggal)"))
    ->pluck('total_volume','year');

            return view('admin.home',compact('volume'));
}
```

Comment: What is `1.A.A.1` here? Column name?

Comment: `whereColumn` compares columns and  `1.A.A.1` does not look like a column

Comment: it's a string name inside subid column

Comment: To match a value then you need to use `->where('subid', '1.A.A.1')`

Comment: okay i think just get my answer,i don't need ->havingRaw('total_volume < 100000000', [1]) and ->whereColumn,To match a value then i just need to use ->where('subid', '1.A.A.1')
thanks....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i just wrote false msyql syntax,what i need to do is just :
**erase ->havingRaw('total_volume < 100000000', [1]) and ->whereColumn**,To match a value then i just need to **use ->where('subid', '1.A.A.1')**

```
public function datavolumechart(){
$string = '1.A.A.1';
$volume = lokasipekerjaan::select(
    DB::raw("YEAR(tanggal) as year"),
    DB::raw("SUM(volume) as total_volume
    "),
)->where('subid','LIKE','%'.$string.'%')->orderBy(DB::raw("WEEK(tanggal)"))
    ->groupBy(DB::raw("WEEK(tanggal)"))
    ->pluck('total_volume','year');

        return view('admin.home',compact('volume'));
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Can you try change to this

```
->whereColumn('subid',`1.A.A.1`)
```

Comment: well it doesn't work....